# Can cdev_init fail

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I am trying initialize a character device, and after going through some debugging, it seems that there is a possibility that I am failing to register the character device properly

```
int rc;
char device_name[32] = "dma_proxy";
static struct class *local_class_p = NULL;

/* Allocate a character device from the kernel for this 
 * driver
 */ 
rc = alloc_chrdev_region(&pchannel_p->dev_node, 0, 1, "dma_proxy");

if (rc) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "unable to get a char device number\n");
    return rc;
}

/* Initialize the ter device data structure before
 * registering the character device with the kernel
 */ 
printk("pchannel_p->cdev addr: %p\n", (void*)&pchannel_p->cdev);
cdev_init(&pchannel_p->cdev, &dm_fops);
pchannel_p->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
rc = cdev_add(&pchannel_p->cdev, pchannel_p->dev_node, 1);

if (rc) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "unable to add char device\n");
    goto init_error1;
}

/* Only one class in sysfs is to be created for multiple channels,
 * create the device in sysfs which will allow the device node 
 * in /dev to be created 
 */
if (!local_class_p) {
    local_class_p = class_create(THIS_MODULE, DRIVER_NAME);

    if (IS_ERR(pchannel_p->dma_device_p->class)) {
        printk(KERN_INFO, "unable to create class\n");
        rc = ERROR;
        goto init_error2;
    }   
}

pchannel_p->class_p = local_class_p;

/* Create the device node in /dev so the device is accessible 
 * as a character device
 */
strcat(device_name, name);
pchannel_p->proxy_device_p = device_create(pchannel_p->class_p, NULL,
                        pchannel_p->dev_node, NULL, device_name);

if (IS_ERR(pchannel_p->proxy_device_p)) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "unable to create the device\n");
    goto init_error3;
}
```

However, perhaps this is not the case. In the open function I print, the i_cdev address of the inode and it matches the printed address in this function.

```
static int local_open(struct inode *ino, struct file *file)
{

    file->private_data = container_of(ino->i_cdev, struct dma_proxy_channel, cdev);
    printk("Inode->cdev addr: %p", (void*)ino->i_cdev);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

pchannel_p->cdev addr: ee9b7194

Inode->cdev addr: ee9b7194

How might I know if my device initialization failed? The /dev/ node is there and in the /sys folder so is the class I created

Comment: What is the `strcat(device_name, name);` call for? Note that `device_create` takes a printf-style format string and variable arguments, so you could call it like: `pchannel_p->proxy_device_p = device_create(pchannel_p->class_p, NULL, pchannel_p->dev_node, NULL, "dma_proxy%s", name);`.

Comment: Your code does not set `rc` before the `goto init_error3;` so perhaps your function is returning 0 instead of a (negative) error code. Also, if `IS_ERR(ptr)` is true, you can use `rc = PTR_ERR(ptr);` to extract the error code from the pointer.

Comment: Also make sure that your error clean-up code reached by the labels `init_error3` etc. clean up the parts that were allocated before returning the error code.

Comment: the strcat is because I am actually making two of these things and they need different names, one for tx and one for rx which gets made into the device name proxy_device_tx or proxy_device_rx

Comment: Can you improve your question? It is not really clear. For example, the code is incomplete (missing all the clean-up part). Then, it is not clear to me *who* must be notified that the initialization failed: user-space program; you, the user; or the kernel? If you have your device instance visible, probably your device initialization was successful (indeed you do not have the error on the output you showed us); on failure you should not see any device instance in `/dev` or `/sys`